# Creating a variable based on data in predefined vectors and discrete outcomes

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Suppose a respondent (id) is asked to make a binary (discrete) choice, either select 1 or 2 in five tasks (t=1,2,3,4,5) (a panel dataset with five observations per respondent).

If a respondent selects choice 1, then the outcome is a fixed value (let say 30 always) but if a respondent selects choice 2, then the outcome is different and depends on which treatment the respondent is in (there is only one treatment per respondent since the respondent is randomly assigned to one treatment only). Let say there are four treatments (a vector) and in each treatment, there are five outcomes if choice 2 is selected.

That is,

treat1= 1,2,3,4,5

treat2= 6,7,8,9,10

treat3= 11,12,13,14,15

treat4= 16,17,18,19,20

For example, in the case of **treat1**, if a respondent in the first task selects choice 2, then the outcome is equal to 1. In the second task, the respondent selects choice 1, the outcome is 30 (as always). In the third task, if a respondent selects choice 2, the outcome is 2 (and not 3). That is if choice 2 is selected for the first time in treat1, then pick the first value from the treat1 sequence; if choice 2 is selected for the second time in treat1, then pick the second value from the treat 2 sequence and so on.

The outcome looks like the below.

```
+----+---+-----------+--------+---------+
| id | t | treatment | choice | outcome |
+----+---+-----------+--------+---------+
|  1 | 1 |         1 |      2 |       1 |
|  1 | 2 |         1 |      1 |      30 |
|  1 | 3 |         1 |      2 |       2 |
|  1 | 4 |         1 |      1 |      30 |
|  1 | 5 |         1 |      2 |       3 |
|  2 | 1 |         3 |      1 |      30 |
|  2 | 2 |         3 |      2 |      11 |
|  2 | 3 |         3 |      2 |      12 |
|  2 | 4 |         3 |      1 |      30 |
|  2 | 5 |         3 |      2 |      13 |
|  3 | 1 |         2 |      2 |       6 |
|  3 | 2 |         2 |      1 |      30 |
|  3 | 3 |         2 |      1 |      30 |
|  3 | 4 |         2 |      1 |      30 |
|  3 | 5 |         2 |      2 |       7 |
|  4 | 1 |         4 |      1 |      30 |
|  4 | 2 |         4 |      1 |      30 |
|  4 | 3 |         4 |      1 |      30 |
|  4 | 4 |         4 |      2 |      16 |
|  4 | 5 |         4 |      1 |      30 |
|  5 | 1 |         2 |      1 |      30 |
|  5 | 2 |         2 |      1 |      30 |
|  5 | 3 |         2 |      1 |      30 |
|  5 | 4 |         2 |      1 |      30 |
|  5 | 5 |         2 |      2 |       6 |
|  . | . |         . |      . |       . |
|  . | . |         . |      . |       . |
|  . | . |         . |      . |       . |
|  . | . |         . |      . |       . |
|  . | . |         . |      . |       . |
+----+---+-----------+--------+---------+
```

Since my data has thousands of observations, I was wondering what would be an efficient way to generate the variable **outcome**.

The *id*, *t*, *treatment*, and *choice* variables are available in my dataset.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To answer your question properly we would need more details. Could you update the data and show what the expected result would look like for `id == 2`? Will `treatment` always be 1? etc.

Comment: @markus, thanks for the comment. I have updated the expected result. The treatment will not be always 1. It could be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. And the respondent will only be assigned to one of the four treatments.

Comment: @NelsonGon, I have checked the question you mentioned but I believe my question is quite different from that. Perhaps, I could be wrong.

Comment: Retracted. It was unclear given there was no sample data. My bad! Please use `dput` to provide sample data.

Comment: @NelsonGon, I am getting a hang of dput. @thothal generated the sample data using the below code ```set.seed(1)
treat_lkp <- list(trt1 = 1:5, trt2 = 6:10, trt3 = 11:15, trt4 = 16:20)
d_in <- expand.grid(task = 1:5, id = 1:5)
d_in$treatment <- paste0("trt", d_in$id %% 4 + 1)
d_in$choice <- sample(2, NROW(d_in), TRUE)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide any sample data, so I create some fake data first

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
treat_lkp <- list(trt1 = 1:5, trt2 = 6:10, trt3 = 11:15, trt4 = 16:20)
d_in <- expand.grid(task = 1:5, id = 1:5)
d_in$treatment <- paste0("trt", d_in$id %% 4 + 1)
d_in$choice <- sample(2, NROW(d_in), TRUE)
```

**tidyverse solution**

I use a simple `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
d_out <- d_in %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(task_new = cumsum(choice == 2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(outcome = {
     l <- treat_lkp[as.character(d_in$treatment)]
     pmap_dbl(list(task = task_new, choice = choice, set = l),
              function(task, choice, set)
                 ifelse(choice == 1, 30, set[task])  
              )}
  )

head(d_out)
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#    task    id treatment choice task_new outcome
#   <int> <int> <chr>      <int>    <int>   <dbl>
# 1     1     1 trt2           1        0      30
# 2     2     1 trt2           1        0      30
# 3     3     1 trt2           2        1       6
# 4     4     1 trt2           2        2       7
# 5     5     1 trt2           1        2      30
# 6     1     2 trt3           2        1      11
```

**Explanation**

You create first a list `l` with the relevant lookup values for your outcome (depends on `treatment`). Then you loop over `task`, `treatment` and `choice` to select either `30` (for `choice == 1`)  or you use the right lookup value from `l`

**Update**

Taking the comment into account, we need now first to create a `task_new` variable which holds the correct position. That is the first `choice == 2` should result in `1` the second in `2` and so on. So we `group_by` `id` and add the counter via `cumsum`. We use `task_new` in the `mutate` call after we ungrouped the data.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation (and generating the sample data). In your output, if you look at observation #3 and #4, the outcomes are 8 and 9 respectively, when choice 2 is selected. However, what I would like value 6 and 7 (and not 8 and 9). Perhaps, I misunderstood your point.

Comment: I misunderstood the problem. Fixed it in my update.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible approach is to organize the treatment into a data.table, then do a join and update by reference when choice=2

```
#the sequence of treatment when choice==2
DT[choice==2, ri := rowid(id)]

#look up treatment for the sequence
DT[choice==2, outcome := treat[.SD, on=.(treatment, ri), val]]

#set outcome to 30 for choice=1
DT[choice==1, outcome := 30]

#delete column
DT[, ri := NULL]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
treat <- data.table(treatment=rep(1:4, each=5),
    ri=rep(1:5, times=4),
    val=1:20)

DT <- fread("id,t,treatment,choice,outcome
1,1,1,2,1
1,2,1,1,30
1,3,1,2,2
1,4,1,1,30
1,5,1,2,3")
DT[, outcome := NULL]
```